# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in line 353

Tags: php

I have some code that was written by me some time ago, anyway I dug it out to use and I am getting the following error.

Below is the code that sits around line 353.

```
$db->Connect('localhost', '*****', '*****', '******');    
foreach($data)  {   

$db->Query("INSERT INTO main (company_name, web_address, address, telephone) VALUES    ('".$data['name']."', '".$data['url']."', '".$data['address']."', '".$data['phone']."')");
} echo "DONE";
```

Line 353 relates to Foreach, Any advice or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) statement is incomplete, you need something like:

```
foreach($dataset as $data)  {
```

Where `$dataset` is the 2 dimensional array that contains all record sets your want to insert in the database.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly though it generated a new error, but cured that problem, thanks.